# Java : How to resize buffered image in pixels?

Tags: java, resize, pixel, bufferedimage

I need to resize the original buffered image to width 100 px with preserved width/height ratio. Below is the code am using. Could someone help me with this ?
Thanks in advance.

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;

BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, width, height, null);
g.dispose();
```

Comment: It doesn't have an error but I think the image was not properly resized in 100 px with preserved width/height ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int imageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
int imageHeight = originalImage.getHeight();
height = imageHeight * width / imageWidth;
// Integer arithmetic doing lossless division last.
```

However height might now be less or more than 100.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at imgscalr, it is a simple single class that does exactly this with a simple set of static methods to use: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/

An example usage would look like:

```
BufferedImage img = Scalr.resize(src, 100);
```

There are a number of advanced features around quality, speed and simple image ops available to you as well if you need them and the library has been deployed in production in numerous projects and web applications.

Comment: 10X for the link @Riyad Kalla. This looks like an excellent replacement for JAI.

Comment: Peharps, I can also try this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, can you try

```
int width = 100;
int height = 100;
height = originalImage.height() / (originalImage.width()/width)
```